# 2 Cascading Deletes in Sql Server between 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

Let's say I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nom] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_People] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BUYER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SELLER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTransaction] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The logic being that the transaction table requires 2 records from the people table, a buyer and a seller.

What I am trying to do is implement cascading delete on both the BUYER_ID and SELLER_ID columns.

However, I can add one (either) without a hitch, but if i try to add second one, when I go to save, I get an error message...

```
Unable to create relationship 'FK_Transactions_Buyer'.  
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Transactions_Buyer' on table 'Transactions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Is there a way to do this without using triggers or are triggers the best way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I end up doing it, and I seriously doubt this is the best way.

I modified the Foreign Keys to NOT enforce Foreign Key Constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Buyer]
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Seller]
```

And also modified the Transaction Table to add a IsDeleted Field

```
[IsDeleted] [bit] NULL
```

Finally I added a Delete trigger to the People table which set IsDeleted to TRUE in the Transaction Tables whenever a Buyer_ID or a Seller_Id is deleted in the People Table

Finally at the end of the trigger, i delete all the records in transaction which have the flag IsDeleted set to true.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[deletePeople]
   ON  [dbo].[People]
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @DeletedId INT
  SELECT @DeletedId = id FROM deleted  
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    Update dbo.Transactions SET IsDeleted = 1 WHERE BUYER_ID = @deletedId or SELLER_ID = @deletedId 
    DELETE FROM dbo.Transactions WHERE IsDeleted = 1
END
```

Like I said I doubt this is a proper practice

Answer (score 1):

An FK constraint on people referencing transaction could cause this.
If that's not the case I think the answer will be to include both keys in one constraint.
If both buyer and seller IDs were to be the same, and the person was deleted, both constraints might seek to delete the same row. 
This is the only scenario I can think of that SQL server might try to avoid...

Apologies I can't be more definitive!

Comment: I did add a constraint required different IDs for buyer and seller in same transaction.  That didn't solve the issue sadly.